# Message Dialog - Jtable

Tags: java, eclipse, java-swing

Primero selecciono dos filas o mas de un JTable y al momento de grabar esas filas seleccionadas, me sale varios mensajes ""El Documento "+doc+" se solicitó correctamente"", (doc es el nombre del documento), y asi siguen saliendo los documentos que han sido grabados,como haria para que solo salga un mensaje de confirmación diciendo que los documentos (Que salga los nombres de los documentos que han sido seleccionados y grabados en el mensaje) hayan sido grabados exitosamente. 
Comparto el codigo que estoy utilizando:

```
protected void btnEnviarActionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        //se crea una variable para que contenga la fila seleccionada de la tabla
        int[] selectedRow = tbDocTransferir.getSelectedRows();
        int i = tbDocTransferir.getSelectedRow();
        //hacemos una condicion de que si la varialbe i es -1 es que no se ha seleccionado ninguna 
        //fila
        if (i == -1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Seleccione la fila que desea solicitar"); 
        }
        else{
            for (int t : selectedRow){
            String codArchivo = (String) tbDocTransferir.getValueAt(t, 0);
            String codCentroCosto = (String) tbDocTransferir.getValueAt(t, 1);
            String tipoArchivo = (String) tbDocTransferir.getValueAt(t, 4);
            String doc = (String) tbDocTransferir.getValueAt(t, 6);
            String nivelArchivo = (String) tbDocTransferir.getValueAt(t, 8);
            String lote = (String) tbDocTransferir.getValueAt(t, 10);
            String fila = (String) tbDocTransferir.getValueAt(t, 11);
            String usuarioSolicita = Constante.idUsuario;
            String fechaSolicita = txtFechaSolicita.getText();
            Objeto object = (Objeto) cboCentroCostoDestino.getSelectedItem();
            String centroCostoDestino = ((Objeto)object).getCodigo();
            String centroCostoOrigen = Constante.c_ccosto;
            MovimientoArchivoDTO x = new MovimientoArchivoDTO();
            x.setC_c_archivo(codArchivo);
            CentroCostoDTO c = new CentroCostoDTO();
            c.setC_ccosto(codCentroCosto);
            c.setC_ccosto(centroCostoOrigen);
            x.setC_ccosto(c);
            x.setC_ccosto_origen(c);
            x.setC_ccosto_destino(centroCostoDestino);
            x.setC_tipo_doc(tipoArchivo);
            x.setC_t_doc(doc);
            x.setC_c_nivel_archivo(nivelArchivo);
            x.setLote(lote);
            x.setFila(fila);
            x.setC_c_usuario_solicita(usuarioSolicita);
            x.setD_dt_solicita(fechaSolicita);
            int estado = xy.RegistrarSolicitudArchivo_SA(x);
            if (estado == 1){
                mensaje("El Documento "+doc+" se solicitó correctamente");
//              ListarDocumento(Constante.c_ccosto, Integer.parseInt(txtFlgEnvia_0.getText()));
                lblDestinoDelDocumento.setVisible(false);
                cboCentroCostoDestino.setVisible(false);
//              cboCentroCostoDestino.setSelectedIndex(0);
            }
            else
                mensaje("Error en enviar");
            }
        }
    }

    void mensaje(String m){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, m);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Crea una variable fuera del método donde almacenes el texto concatenado,

luego dentro del form concatenas los valores de **doc** a la variable **texto_concatenado**

finalmente fuera del form usas el **JOptionPane** para mostrar el texto final.
La idea es esta:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String docs = "documentos solicitados\n";

    //este sería tu for
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        //aqui concatenas, en vez de i sera el valor de doc
        docs += i + "\n";
    }
    //finalmente fuera del for muestras el mensaje
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,docs);

}
```

Comment: masomenos alguna idea de como implementarlo

Comment: dame un momento

Comment: he editado mi respuesta, revísela

Answer (score 0):

En el momento que lo muestras por pantalla, añadelo a un array de Strings, y luego en el Dialog mediante un for concadenalos y los muestras.

Algo así:

```
String[] docs = new String[selectedRows.lengh];
//aqui tu for
for(int t : selectedRows){
    ... tu código ...
    mensaje(doc);
    docs[t] = doc;
}
//fin del for
String mensaje = "";
for (int indice : docs){
     mensaje += "Documento número "+(indice+1)+": "+docs[indice] + ".\n"
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,mensaje);
```

Comment: me sale un error en docs en el siguiente codigo "for (int indice : docs)", sale un mensaje que dice: Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type String to int